# nuxt auth : Google provider return invalid_request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs, nuxt-auth

I try to set google authentication with Nuxt Auth module, but I got following error from google:

```
Error 400 : invalid_request
Parameter not allowed for this message type: nonce
```

Here is my config

```js
// nuxt.config.js
modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/auth-next"],
auth: {
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  },
  redirect: {
    login: "/login",
    logout: "/",
    callback: false,
    home: "/",

  },
  strategies: {
         google: { clientId: "MyClientID", codeChallengeMethod: "" }
  }
}
```

And how i call the google auth in my component:

```js
login(){
   this.$auth.loginWith("google").then( result => console.log(result) )
}
```

I also try to run official demo from here:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/tree/dev/demo
But I got the same error.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem

Comment: @Abid did you try to switch nuxt auth version ?

Comment: yeah. V5 hase some problem

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue but setting <strike>`responseType: 'code'`</strike> worked for me.

**EDIT:** Set `responseType: "id_token token"` for an **implicit grant flow** and to get redirected to your Nuxt app with an access token by Google. This whole OAuth topic has always been quite confusing to me and there's so much misinformation out there on what to do and what not to do in terms of security. I have found the following article to be very helpful and demystify the various OAuth flows: https://itnext.io/an-oauth-2-0-introduction-for-beginners-6e386b19f7a9 However if you do not want to expose the access token on the front end and rather obtain it in your back end then you must use the **code grant flow** by setting `responseType: "code"` and set up your back end properly. I ended up using the code grant flow but I assume that most people find the implicit grant flow more convenient.

Here's the full snippet:

```js
export default {
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/auth-next"],
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      google: {
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        redirectUri: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/auth/google/callback`,
        codeChallengeMethod: "",
        responseType: "id_token token",
      },
    },
  },
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  },
};
```

Comment: If you change the responseType to code, then you will be able to select a gmail account but the redirection from /login to /home (or whatever you have) no longer works

Comment: @DamianPerez I have edited my answer and I hope it gives more clarity now. If you change the response type to `responseType: "id_token token"` then you should be redirected to your Nuxt app.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related with the version of Nuxt Auth.

Maybe this feature is not ready in `@nuxtjs/auth-next`

So i run

```
npm install @nuxtjs/auth@latest --save
```

Then update nuxt.config.json

1. replace `@nuxtjs/auth-next` with `@nuxtjs/auth`
2. replace `clientId` with `client_id`

```js
// nuxt.config.js
modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/auth"],
auth: {
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  },
  redirect: {
    login: "/login",
    logout: "/",
    callback: false,
    home: "/",

  },
  strategies: {
         google: { client_id: "MyClientID"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in auth-next and auth0 the setting of `responseType` let me bypass the problem, my working config looks like:

```
auth0: {
  logoutRedirectUri: process.env.BASE_URL,
  domain: String(process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN).replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, ''),
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  scope: ['read:reports', 'read:roles', 'create:client_grants', 'offline_access'], // 'openid', 'profile', 'email' default added
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
  responseType: 'token',
  accessType: 'offline',
  grantType: 'client_credentials',
  redirectUri: process.env.BASE_URL + '/callback',
  codeChallengeMethod: 'S256'
}
```